# Программа вызывает исключние и не работает

Tags: c

Начинаю изучать Си. Задача состоит в том, чтобы подсчитать в строке S колличество вхождений подстроки s1.

Была создана программа:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void main()
{
    char string[100];
    scanf_s("%s", &string);
    char *substring[100];
    scanf_s("%s", &substring);
    int c = 0;
    char* p = strstr(string, substring);
    while (p)
    {
        c++;
        p = strstr(string, substring);
    }
    printf("%d", p);
}
```

Но введении строки **string**, появляется исключение: ***Вызвано исключение по адресу 0x63B1EF8C (ucrtbased.dll) в Lab.exe: 0xC0000005: нарушение прав доступа при записи по адресу 0x01311000.***

Не могу понять, в чём ошибка, заранее спасибо за помощь.

Comment: ¿Куда по-вашему указывает указатель `&substring`?

Comment: Интересно, что вы вообще хотели добиться в `scanf_s("%s", &substring);`? :) Вы, компилируя, на предупреждения компилятора не реагируете из каких соображений?.. Да, а еще интересно — вы всерьез надеетесь, что если `p` не `NULL`, то цикл когда-то закончится? И понимаете, что все, что может вывести ваша программа — если исправить проблемы со вводом и повезет - это 0?

Comment: если строка есть - будет бесконечный цикл. и не понятно, что хочется вывести в конце

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
void main()
{
    #define  SIZE  200
    char string[SIZE];
    gets_s(string, SIZE);
    char substring[SIZE];
    gets_s(substring, SIZE);
    int c = 0;
    for(char* p = strstr(string, substring);
        p; p = strstr(p+1, substring)) ++c;
    printf("%d", c);
}
```